# Running extension cord and Cat6a through wood closet shelf?

Tags: wiring, code-compliance, power

I'm in the process of installing a wireless router on a closet shelf, and I'd like to know the proper procedure for routing the extension cord and Cat6a cable. Per the picture below:

- The extension cord will go into the top hole that goes through the
  shelf
- The Cat6a cable will go into the bottom hole that goes through the
  wall

What needs to be done to make this code compliant? Also, the 2nd picture shows the bottom hole that goes through the wall where the Cat6a will be routed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% clear on your description but the NEC and CEC prohibit extension cords in the walls.  There is more info at this link, obviously biased but in this case correct:

http://www.powerbridgesolution.com/info/extensioncordwarning.html

From NEC:

> 400.8 Uses Not Permitted (ref. Extension Cord) Flexible cords and cables shall not be used for the following:
>
> ```
>       (1) As a substitute for the fixed wiring of a structure 
>       (2) Where run through holes in walls, structural ceilings, suspended ceilings, dropped ceilings, or floors 
>       (3) Where run through doorways, windows, or similar openings 
>       (4) Where attached to building surfaces 
>       (5) Where concealed by walls, floors, or ceilings or located above suspended or dropped ceilings
> ```

The Cat6, generally nothing to worry about, may not be code compliant depending on the locale, but believe me telcos and cable tv companies do worse things on a daily basis most places, low voltage is much safer.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll run just the Cat6a through the wall then.

Comment: @eclipsis Also, if you're truly using an "extension cord", and not the devices power cord. 400.8(1) applies, and says you can't use an extension cord as substitute for fixed wiring.  You should install a code compliant receptacle, where the device is to be installed.